# Schema with elements, attributes, and text

Tags: xsd

I am having trouble getting this XML file to validate against my schema, which doesn't have syntax errors according to my XML editor.  I am trying to make course an complexType element, but it keeps telling me I can't.  The XML is correct, it is definitely something with my schema, I just can't figure it out.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<courses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="course_offerings.xsd">

  <course id="WEB225">
    <name>Web Development II</name>
    <offered>Spring</offered>
    <pre_reqs>WEB125</pre_reqs>
  </course>

  <course id="WEB125">
    <name>Web Development I</name>
    <offered>Fall</offered>
  </course>

  <course id="WEB325">
    <name>Client-Side Scripting</name>
    <offered>Spring</offered>
    <offered>Fall</offered>
    <pre_reqs>WEB225</pre_reqs>
  </course>

</courses>
```

And here is my schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="courses">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="course" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="offered" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="pre_reqs" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>


      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: **what error? please mention it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned what error you are getting, I'm providing what I can observe..

1. In your XML you have included this statement: `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="course_offerings.xsd"` This means it is your default XML schema. You need to verify the name of schema and make sure it is present in default path.. (same as that of XML file). Otherwise you may end up seeing an error `unable to locate schema 
   course_offerings.xsd`
2. You have declared  `<xs:element name="course" type="xs:string"/>` as string .. that should not be the case.. In your XML it's a complexType, ie, an element having child elements inturn..

   1. All these elements name, offered, pre_reqs should come under this complexType
   2. Attribute should be within the scope of this complexType..

       Otherwise you would face not just one but **multiple errors since the definition of element course is invalid**

Refer the sample XSD below:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="courses">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="course">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="offered" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="pre_reqs" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The above mentioned style is hierarchical, there is an alternative method to write a schema file.. If you understand the current consequences and if you wish to know further then I will let you know..

For now this much explanation should be good..

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was getting multiple errors, I should have put that in my original message.  Sorry.

Comment: @user2297971, Follow my suggestion.. let me know if you need any more help and Check the tick mark to accept my answer if it was helpful for you..